# Can I have the JVM kill a started process when it exits?

Tags: java, process

I just realized that all of the processes I'm starting aren't dying when the JVM exits. Is there a way for me to close a `Process` with the JVM exits, kind of like `File.deleteOnExit()`?

Comment: In most circumstances exiting the JVM and terminating the process are synonymous with each other. Could you provide a bit more detail on what exactly is happening in your case (or at least what the symptoms are)?

Comment: `Runtime.addShutdownHook` and do whatever you have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the `.waitFor()` method on each `Process` before exiting.

If you can't control that process as well as you'd like, you could use `Runtime.addShutdownHook()`:

```
final Process process = startNewProcess();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        process.waitFor();
    }
}));
```

I really don't recommend the latter solution if possible, though. If the JVM doesn't have a chance to clean itself up, then the process will still be running if it is forcibly killed.

Comment: So `waitFor()` will kill the process on JVM exit? I'm already running `waitFor()`, but maybe it isn't being called due to IO. I'll investigate.

Comment: `waitFor()` will block the running thread until the process ends. I'm saying you should put it at the end of your normal flow. Otherwise you can use my alternative solution.

Comment: Is it possible to send a signal to the process, like Ctrl+C?

Comment: If you want to destroy the process outright, you can use `process.destroy()`. What's your real situation and your real goal? You're not really being very clear or specific.

Comment: I've had to write a server in Python to serve out values obtained through a driver which doesn't have an API in Java. Java starts the process, then connects over TCP. When my Java server shuts down, it should shut down the process cleanly so that the Python server can reset things before exiting. A keyboard interrupt (Ctrl+C) works fine for this.

Comment: I'd say `process.destroy()` is what you want, then. It seems to send SIGTERM or equivalent, so the process should theoretically be able to clean itself up if it's well-behaved.

Comment: I ended up just inventing a message to send to the server process to indicate that it should shut down. Works.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a list of all running processes and then use Process.destroy() to shut them down inside a shutdown hook like Platinum Azure mentioned.

You also need to clean the list up when the processes are finished.  If you have code that is already calling process.waitFor() then that could cleanup the list.

The destroy method forcibly shuts down the process, possibly corrupting anything it is doing, so you should take care with using it.

If you control the other processes, then signaling it to shutdown and then waiting for it to finish would be advisable over calling destroy.